# Show that $|f(z)|\le M\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n|z-z_k|}{\prod_{k=1}^n|z+\overline{z_k}|}$ on the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be analytic on $H=\{z:\Re(z)\ge 0\}$. Suppose that:
>
> - There exists $M>0$ such that if $\Re(z)=0$ then $|f(z)|\le M$.
> - There are $z_1,...,z_n$ such that $\Re(z_k)>0$ and $f(z_k)=0$.
>
> Prove that for all $z\in H$: $$|f(z)|\le M\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n|z-z_k|}{\prod_{k=1}^n|z+\overline{z_k}|}.$$

This is suppose to be solved with the Maximum Modulus Theorem. But I don't know exactly which one. Since $f$ shouldn't be neccesary constant, the theorem must be this:

> **M. M. Theorem**: Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ a bounded domain. Let $f$ be continuous on $\overline{U}$ and analytic on $U$. Then: $$\max\{|f(z)|:z\in\overline{U}\}=\max\{|f(z)|:z\in\partial U\}.$$

Since we need a bounded domain, let $U$ be the unit disk and consider the Möbius transformation $T(z)=\dfrac{-z-1}{z-1}$, so $T$ sends $U$ onto the right half plane.

By the M. M. Theorem, the maximum value of $|f\circ T|$ on $\overline{U}$ occurrs on the unit circle $|z|=1$. But if $|z|=1$, by the first point we have $|f(T(z))|\le M$. Therefore $|f(T(z))|\le M$ for all $z\in\overline{U}$.

But isn't it true that $T(\overline{U})=H$ and then $|f(z)|\le M$ for all $z\in H$? This is not the desired inequality. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not true. The function $e^z$ is a counterexample with $n=0$ (if you don't like $n=0$, the function $(1-z)e^z/(1+z)$ is a counterexample with $n=1$.) You're leaving out a crucial hypothesis (or the author left it out).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, thank you. It seems the autor left it out. If anyone knows what a crucial hypothesis could it be, please let me know.

Comment: Hard to believe. Where is this from? Look again - what you wrote is _exactly_ what it says?

Comment: It is from here. It is in spanish though http://www.posgradomatematicas.unam.mx/contenidoEstatico/archivo/files/pdf/Examenes_Generales/Analisis/Analisis2014-2.pdf

Comment: Author's typo. It should be:
There exists $M>0$ such that if $\Re(z)\ge 0 $ then $|f(z)|\le M$

Comment: Heh, I was about to say i don't read Spanish (Portugese?), but it turns out I can read enough to see that sure enough, the problem asks what you said. It's wrong. I'll post an answer...

Comment: @ts375_zk26 so basically $|f|$ must be less or equal to $M$ on all of its domain $H$?

Comment: No! It has to be bounded by _something_ on the entire domain, _not_ by $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result as stated is not true. The function $e^z$ is a counterexample with $n=0$; this can easily be modified to give a counterexample for $n>0$.

The result becomes true if we assume in addition that $f$ is *bounded*. We need the following version of MMT:

**Theorem.** Suppose $f$ is analytic and bounded in the region $\Re z\ge0$. If $|f(z)|\le M$ for all $z$ with $\Re z=0$ then $|f(z)|\le M$ for all $z$ with $\Re z > 0$.

**Proof.** The simplest proof may be a Phragmen-Lindelofish argument. For $\epsilon>0$ let $$g_\epsilon(z)=f(z)/(1+\epsilon z).$$Then $|g_\epsilon(z)|\le M$ for $\Re z=0$. And *also* $g_\epsilon\to0$ at infinity, *since* $f$ is bounded. So the lim sup of $g_\epsilon$ is less than or equal to $M$ at every boundary point in the extended plane, hence a suitable version of MMT shows that $|g_\epsilon|\le M$ in $\Re z>0$. Now let $\epsilon\to0$. QED.

Now to do the problem. Given $f$ as in the problem, assuming $f$ is also bounded, let $g=$???. Applying the theorem to $g$ shows that $|g|\le M$ in the right half plane, and that shows that $f$ satisfies the conclusion. (Saying $|g|\le M$ implies what you need should be a good hint what $g$ should be...)

---

**The Point:** When you figure out what function $g$ you need to apply the theorem to to do the problem, you see that it's *not* obvious that $|g|\le M$ in the entire region, even if we begin by assuming thet $|f|\le M$ in the entire region. But it *is* clear that $g$ is bounded (by *something*, we don't know what) in the entire region, and that $|g|\le M$ on the imaginary axis. Hence the theorem shows that $|g|\le M$  everywhere. (In other words, even if we assume $|f|\le M$ everywhere to start we still need that theorem.)

Comment: Some questions. From what you wrote it is pretty obvious that $g=f/h$ where $h(z)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n|z-z_k|}{\prod_{k=1}^n|z+\overline{z_k}|}$. Then $g$ is analytic because $h$ has the zeros $z_k's$ and they are simple zeros. But I don't see why is it $g$ bounded? The theorem you wrote says $g$ must be bounded in order to apply it. Second question is, why $|g|\le M$ in $\Re(z)=0$? Perhaps it is $|h(z)|=1$ for all $\Re (z)=0$?

Comment: First, $h$ is not quite what you say. We want $h$ to be holomorphic; leave out the absolute value signs. Yes, $|h(z)|=1$ for $\Re z=0$; this follows from the fact that $|\overline\alpha|=|\alpha|$. Why is $f/h$ bounded? Well, it's bounded in a neighborhood of each $z_k$ because it's continuous. And if $z$ satisfies $|z-z_k|>\delta>0$ for every $k$ you can show directly that $|1/h(z)|$ is less than or equal to _something_ (something independent of $z$).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to wipe out the absolute values, but I understood it now. Thanks again.